# how can i implement sass-lint or less-lint for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sass-lint

He everyone,

perhaps im asking a stupid question but i want to know if i can integrate [sass-lint](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint) or [less-hint](https://github.com/lesshint/lesshint) with jenkins. We already have csslint implemented in jenkins. I already have search trough the internet but couldn't find anything interested regarding this topic.